# Dropping step function in integral

Tags: integration

I have a hopefully very simple question about step functions inside of integrals.

I have an integral from minus infinity to plus infinity which contains the unit step function. Am I allowed to drop the step function and start the integral at 0 instead of minus infinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we suppose that you have this definition:

[image]

then yes, you can start the integral at $0$.